# C++ / Mysql Connector : undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'

Tags: c++, mysql, undefined-reference, connector

I've found some topics on this forum concerning the same error, but I didn't find the solution in it.

I'm trying to make work C++ & Mysql Connector on Ubuntu 11.04.
My error is (after following official Mysql tutorial)

```
/tmp/ccDmH4pd.o: In function `main':
mysql.cpp:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `get_driver_instance'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code :

```
int main(){     
    sql::Driver*        driver; // Create a pointer to a MySQL driver object
    sql::Connection*    dbConn; // Create a pointer to a database connection object
    sql::Statement*     stmt;   // Create a pointer to a Statement object to hold our SQL commands
    sql::ResultSet*     res;    // Create a pointer to a ResultSet object to hold the results of any queries we run

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);


        delete dbConn;
        return 0;
    }
```

Here are my includes :

```
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"

// Include the Connector/C++ headers
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"
```

Thanks in advance everybody

Touki

Comment: How are you compiling/linking?

Answer (score 0):

The `get_driver_instance()` function is not in the global namespace but in ::sql::mysql. So you have to use the proper name:

```
::sql::Driver *driver = ::sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();
```

Comment: Thanks,

The problem is still there with now : <pre>undefined reference to `sql::mysql::get_driver_instance()'</pre>

If I check : /usr/include/cppconn

The file driver.h contains :

    /* namespace sql */
    
    extern "C"
    {
     CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC sql::Driver * get_driver_instance();
    }

Any Ideas ?

Comment: In my code I'm including driver/mysql_public_iface.h and driver/mysql_driver.h .. and then: what's your linker/compile command?

Comment: I didn't need to include other files. I just reinstalled mysql_connector manually instead of the apt-get way. And there is compatibility problem, so I had to change the default cpp library used or recompiled mysql_connector with another one.

Answer (score -1):

```
LIBPATH = -L/usr/lib/ -lmysqlcppconn -lmysqlclient_r
```